# How to pass child element of div to controller through ajax in larvavel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, parent-child, element

I want to pass child element of div through ajax call to controller in laravel project clicking the button.

Here the div..`

```
 <button type="button" id="saveForm" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Save</button>

<div class="col-9 canvas">
      <input type="text"  name="firstname" placeholder="email">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="password" >
      <input type="button" onclick="myBtn()" value="login">
</div>
```

For passing the elemnt to the controller I used the following ajax code..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#saveForm").click(function(){
          var canvas = $(".canvas");

          $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('save.form') }}",
          type: "post",
          data:{data:canvas},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

But in the way I can't pass the child element of div .
How can I pass the child element?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for passing html of .canvas block

```
var canvas = $(".canvas")[0].outerHTML;
```

and if you are looking for inside of .canvas html then

```
var canvas = $(".canvas").html();
```

full code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#saveForm").click(function(){
          var canvas = $(".canvas")[0].outerHTML;

          $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('save.form') }}",
          type: "post",
          data:{data:canvas,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```